# Get number of records deleted sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, rowcount

I want to get the row count of how many records have been deleted. The below query returns the number of records that will be affected, but

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM suppliers
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT customers.customer_name
    FROM customers
    WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id
    AND customer_id > 25 );
```

I need something like this, after the rows have been deleted, I can show the number of records that have been deleted on the front end.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM suppliers(
DELETE from supplier(
    WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT customers.customer_name
        FROM customers
        WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id
        AND customer_id > 25 ));
```

I don't want to run the query twice, one to get the number of records that will be deleted, if its greater than 0, then I run the second query to delete the records.

Comment: How are you invoking this SQL?  This is important because most toolsets will return the number of affected records automatically when you run a DELETE command.  For example, in Java's JDBC architecture, the `executeUpdate` command returns an integer representing the number deleted or updated (depending on the SQL).

Comment: What about @@ROWCOUNT?

Comment: You should use the `RETURNING INTO` clause.  The exact method depends on how you are making the call, but the documentation is here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354.

Comment: @schtever I'm using REST model services to invoke the query, all I get back is `json` and `jquery` `jsonp`  to invoke.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `RETURNING INTO` clause to get all the rows being deleted -- and then count those.

An easier way for just the count is `SQL%ROWCOUNT` in PL/SQL code.  Something like this:

```
BEGIN
    DELETE from supplier(
        WHERE EXISTS
          ( SELECT customers.customer_name
            FROM customers
            WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id
            AND customer_id > 25 );
    dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use

```
declare @countDelete int
set nocount on
delete tablename
where ..
select @@ROWCOUNT
```